# When do we elide “dove è” into “dov'è”?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I have gone through various web pages about elision in Italian. All of them mentioned that we usually elide words like *di, la, le, nella, questo*, et cetera. But none of them mentioned the elision of *gli* and *dove*.

I searched for more and learned that words like *gl'insulti* are old usages and we don't usually elide *gli* nowadays. But what about *dove*? I see *where is* translated into **dov'è** but no one told me elision goes like that. When (in what cases) is *dove è* elided into *dov'è*?

Comment: I'd say to *always* use *dov’è* in questions; in other contexts the usage is varied. It used to be elided also in front of *ha*, for instance, but not in current usage.

Comment: You can also elide many other words: _senza_ (_senz'altro_), _mezzo/a_ (_mezz'ora_), _quando_ (_quand'ecco che..._), _santo_ (_sant'Antonio_), _bello_ (_bell'uomo_) and so on. Apparently, it is simply the case that the websites you looked up didn't pick _dove_ in their examples.

Comment: @egreg Like *Where have you gone?* -> *Dov'hai andato?* (?)

Comment: @iBug *Andare* wants the auxiliary verb *essere*, so it should be *dove sei andato?*. But the idea is something like *dov'hai messo?* (not current usage). Look at [this Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dov%27ha%22)

Comment: @egreg: Nel link che hai messo, mi fa quasi ridere quel "Publi Ovidi Nasó", col nome così catalanizzato (dovuto al fatto che il libro digitalizzato proviene da Cubelles, che è il paese accanto a quello dove sono nata io).

Comment: @iBug, could you make clear whether your question is the one in the tile (“When do we elide...”) or the one in the text (which seem to be whether _dove_ is different from other word with respect to elision)?

Comment: I'd add that while it's true that nowadays _gl'i-_ is seldom seen in written language, _gli_ is normally elided  with every vowel in spoken language (you won't usually read the _i_ in _gli altri_)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use *dov'è* rather than *dove è* pretty much always when it is used in an interrogative clause, both direct (*L'ho perso di vista. Dov'è andato?*) and indirect (*Non so dov'è andato*).

Less so in relative clause, such as *la casa dove è nato Enrico Fermi*; for some reason, *dov'è*, while not incorrect, may look somewhat old-fashioned here.

Comment: In realtà esempi dell’uso di “dov’è” in contesti affermativi se ne trovano parecchi nello scritto. Per cui non sono sicuro che sia una forma “strana” da usare. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dov%27%C3%A8%20nato%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_it

Comment: @Gio: Più che “strano” intendevo “antiquato”: ora comunque ho modificato. Purtroppo, cercare solo “dov'è nato” mette insieme testi moderni, testi antichi e testi dove “dov'è nato” è una domanda e quindi ricade nel primo caso.